# Deploying Nuxt.js and Nest.js together

Tags: rest, architecture, nuxt.js, nestjs, single-page-application

I have

- Frontend SPA app written in Nuxt.js 2
- Backend API for that SPA written in Nest.js

I don't know if I should host Frontend and Backend separately or use Nest's **Serve Static** module.

Hosting SPA in Nest.js is more convenient but I'm not sure if it's the best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend splitting the frontend and backend, it will be:

- cheaper
- simpler to manage/debug/organize yourself
- more suited to the given stack: performance, charge, price

I'm not sure how Nest is able to serve anything static but the points above are still totally valid.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. [Here](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static) is the module I mentioned.

Comment: @Daniel that is in case you want to have both backend and frontend in the same place. I do not recommend either, keep separate git repos.